# php system, python and utf-8

Tags: php, python, encoding, system, decoding

I have a python program running very well. It connects to several websites and outputs the desired information. Since not all websites are encoded with utf-8, I am requesting the charset from the headers and using `unicode(string, encoding)` method to decode (I am not sure whether its the appropriate way to do this but it works pretty well). When I run the python program I receive no ??? marks and it works fine. But when I run the program using php's `system` function, I receive this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0131' in position 41: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is a python specific error but what confuses me is that I don't receive this error when I run the program using the terminal. I only receive this when I use php's `system` function and call the program from php. What may be the cause behind this problem?

Here is a sample code:

php code that calls python program:

```
system("python somefile.py $search") // where $search is the variable coming from an input
```

python code:

```
encoding = "iso-8859-9"
l = "some string here with latin characters"
print unicode("<div class='line'>%s</div>" % l, encoding)
# when I run this code from terminal it works perfect and I receive no ??? marks
# when I run this code from php, I receive the error above
```

Comment: It's probably an environment variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [PrintFails wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails):

> When Python finds its output attached to a terminal, it sets the
>   `sys.stdout.encoding` attribute to the terminal's encoding. The print
>   statement's handler will automatically encode unicode arguments into
>   str output.

This is why your program works when called from the terminal.

> When Python does not detect the desired character set of the
>   output, it sets sys.stdout.encoding to None, and print will invoke the
>   "ascii" codec.

This is why your program fails when called from php.
To make it work when called from php, you need to make explicit what encoding `print` should use. For example, to make explicit that you want the output encoded in `utf-8` (when not attached to a terminal):

```
ENCODING = sys.stdout.encoding if sys.stdout.encoding else 'utf-8'
print unicode("<div class='line'>%s</div>" % l, encoding).encode(ENCODING)
```

---

Alternatively, you could set the [PYTHONIOENCODING environment variable](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING).
Then your code should work without changes (both from the terminal and when called from php).

Answer (score 2):

When you run the python script in your terminal, your terminal is likely to be encoded in UTF8 (specially if you are using linux or mac).

When you set `l` variable to `"some string with latin characters"`, that string will be encoded to the default encoding, if you are using a terminal `l` will be UTF8 and the script wont crash.

A little tip: if you have a string encoded in latin1 and you want it in unicode you can do:

`variable.decode('latin1')`