# PHP system() fail silently when calling a python script that processes file with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, php-7, php-7.2

**Tl;dr:** Consider using python framework Bottle instead of PHP. If you can't, I have python2-specific solution link at the bottom of this post.

I made simple markov chain python program. It operates on two wordlists, `greek.txt` and `japanese.txt`. Note that `japanese.txt` contains the `Ō` character, but the problem persisted even when I replaced the characters with regular `O`.

I want to make really simple, small and dirty PHP API.

When I call PHP file, it should echo output of command `python3 markov-chain.py $_GET['file'] 10 $_GET['min'] $_GET['max']`.

I have this:

```php
<?php
if(isset($_GET["file"]) && isset($_GET["min"]) && isset($_GET["max"])) {
    if($_GET["file"] != null && $_GET["min"] != null && $_GET["max"] != null && is_numeric($_GET["min"]) && is_numeric($_GET["max"])) {
        # Yeah, it should be fine. Just check for $file in whitelist
        $filename = $_GET["file"];
        $min_len = $_GET["min"];
        $max_len = $_GET["max"];
        $count = 10;
        if( $filename === "japanese.txt" || $filename == "greek.txt" ) {
            $command = 'python3 markov-chain.py ' . $filename . ' ' . $count . ' ' . $min_len . ' ' . $max_len;
            echo($command);
            echo(system($command, $statuscode));
            echo('S:'.$statuscode);
            echo('E:'.error_get_last());
        }
    }
}
?>
```

When I call this on the `greek.txt` wordlist, everything works as expected. However, when I call it on `japanese.txt`, status code is `1` and nothing is sent to output of `system()`. When I copy&paste the generated command into terminal, it works without issues even for the `japanese.txt` variant.

I tried to make `test.sh` file that would have hardcoded arguments:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
python3 markov-chain.py greek.txt 10 3 6 2>> errorlog.txt
```

When I call this file from PHP, it works. However when I change the `test.sh` file to work with `japanese.txt` wordlist, I still get nothing as an output and `1` as status code. Invoking the `test.sh` from terminal works perfectly for both variants (greek and japanese). Nothing is written to error log file (the file isn't even created!) when I call the `test.sh` from PHP.

[Greek wordlist](http://167.71.35.104/api/greek.txt)
[Japanese wordlist](http://167.71.35.104/api/japanese.txt)

Edit:

Greek wordlist is ASCII, and Japanese wordlist is UTF-8, so PHP doesn't accept (or Python doesn't correctly send) UTF-8 encoding.

Edit:

Not really a solution, but I ended up switching to Python framework [Bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/), it's exactly why I used PHP: I just write it in one file and it... works. Great for simple APIs I just need to quickly hack together.

Concerning the issue with UTF-8, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362576/php-system-python-and-utf-8), but was not able to solve my problem anyway. Hopefully it helps someone.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind when you describe it works fine with Greek and not so well with Japanese is that this is potentially an encoding issue. Do you mind sharing  some of your python code?

Comment: You should probably look into using [escapeshellarg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) or [escapeshellcmd()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) when using `system()` together with user input

Comment: @IsThisJavascript The greek is ASCII and japanese is UTF-8, so I guess you're right and this is the problem. However Python processes both just fine. Here's the python code: https://gist.github.com/SoptikHa2/7e05c7d7da4946a50eb86925a35b6856

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks, it looks like I should've used this. However the issue seems to be that PHP is unable to retrieve UTF-8 text from `system(...)` for some reason?